# Period of a solution in a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

This is more of a general question, which keeps confusing me when solving trigonometric equations. When is the period $k\pi$, and when is it $2k\pi$?

For example, if I need to solve $\tan x=1$, is the correct solution $\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi$? Or should I write it as  $\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi$ **and** $\frac{5\pi}{4}+2n\pi$?

The same problem appears when I need to solve for $\sin x=1$ or $\cos x=1$ (and also $\sin x=0$ or $\cos x=0$)

Comment: The solution $\pi/4$ is wrong !

Comment: How did you find $\pi/4+k\pi$ as a solution?

Comment: I made a mistake, it's supposed to be tanx=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin$ and $\cos$ have period $2\pi$ and $\tan$ has period $\pi$.

When solving an equation, make sure to list all roots in a period.

$\tan x=0\implies x=0$ in $[0,\pi)$, i.e. $x=k\pi$.

$\tan x=1\implies x=\dfrac\pi4$ in $[0,\pi)$, i.e. $x=\dfrac\pi4+k\pi$.

$\sin x=0\implies x=0$ or $x=\pi$ in $[0,2\pi)$, i.e. $x=k\pi$.

$\sin x=1\implies x=\dfrac\pi2$ in $[0,2\pi)$, i.e. $x=\dfrac\pi2+2k\pi$.

$\cos x=0\implies x=\dfrac\pi2$ or $x=\dfrac{3\pi}2$ in $[0,2\pi)$, i.e. $x=\dfrac\pi2+k\pi$.

$\cos x=1\implies x=0$ in $[0,2\pi)$, i.e. $x=2k\pi$.